# HEMA Longsword Compasses

Tags: italian-longsword

I am a novice swordsman, learning Italian Longsword from Guy Windsor's *[The Swordsman's Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9526793404)*, which so far has been a very helpful and instructive book. I have a question concerning the *Mulinello* (Windmill, or Compass) exercise, as the pictures and wording only explain so much.

When *Mulinello* are done in reverse, you end up in something like *Posta Longa* (Long Position) or *Posta Finestra* (Window Position), but with your false edge up. The golden rule for guards is to go from a guard to a guard. **Given this, how do you from your awkward "post-reverse-Mulinello" stance to a proper one?** (As a bonus question: would this situation come up in sparring without you being totally exposed?)

After some experimentation, I have found some solutions, but I do not trust my opinion as a novice. They are:

1. Simply twist your wrists around into *Posta Longa* or *Posta Breve*
2. Perform another *Mulinello* to get to *Posta Longa*
3. Go into *Posta Finestra*.

It should be noted that I am looking for an answer from a someone with Historical European Martial Arts (HEMA) background. I would make the HEMA tag, but I don't have the requisite reputation here yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, some time with further exercises, and more experience, I can say that a reverse compass (*Muelleno*) gives you the following options:

1. You may use your stance to strike a blow in sparring matches. Ideally, the compass you performed is part of the strike, with you stepping into it. This is seen by Arto Fama vs Matt Easton in their match [here](https://youtu.be/viCVrexfHNc?t=8m2s). Your final position will not be in one of Fiore's Positions/Stances. Your sword's point, however, goes into your opponent. You score a point, or your opponent is wounded. You may notice in that particular instance that the compass covers his body still.
2. *Muelleno* again to come into *Posta Longa* or *Posta Breve*. This works because you can quickly come into a different line. Properly performed compasses will keep you covered from most attacks.
3. Going into *Posta Finestra*. This is easily accomplished by stepping back one step.
4. Twist your arms around again to *Posta Longa* or *Posta Breve*.
5. Lower your sword to get into *Posta Mezzo Ferro*, Middle Iron Door.

It should be noted that your responses all depend on what your opponent chooses to do in response to your attack.

---

For the german schooled swordsmen out there:

- *Posta Longa* is an extended *Pflug*, or a position you get to after performing a vertical or near-vertical cut.
- *Posta Breve* is *Pflug* (Plough), differentiated by name only.
- *Posta Mezzo Ferro* is "[Aubler](http://www.thearma.org/pdf/Fight-Earnestly.pdf)" or Fool's Stance, once again differentiated by name only.

As a final note, *Muelleno* (compasses) are not strictly historical techniques, they were very likely used. It seems most people start naturally doing them during the course of other exercises. The formal identification and teaching of them did not occur until later. (This note is from Guy Windsor's *Swordsman's Companion*.)